# Workaround to instagram_manage_messages for reading instagram direct messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I have a backend application doing requests to the conversations endpoint of Graph API to fetch direct messages on instagram.

I failed to be granted the instagram_manage_messages permission as my app doesnt provide a frontend where the reviewer can test things. Apparently, they really want to play with the frontend, even when there's no frontend...

My question is : Is there any other permission we can use to fetch instagram messages from Graph API (only read operations)?

Thanks all.

Comment: No, there is not. They have review instructions for "server-to-server" apps, if that fits your use case. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/resources/sample-submissions/server-to-server